# Update JSON with jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to update a JSON file with the value of a textarea using jquery push. I'm receiving the following error: " JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference"

My jquery:

```
function submittedMsg(ctx) {
var id = $('.msg-input form').attr('id');
var newMsg = $('.msg-input textarea').val();

var url = "/ajax.aspx?vtl=ajax-conversation-json&cv=" + id;     

$.getJSON(url, function (messageString, message) {
    var message = [];

    message.push({
        msgcontent: newMsg,
        sendname: sendRname,
        mbrhref: mbrUrl,
        datetime: ""
    });
});
}
```

My JSON:

```
{
"messageString" :
[

{ "subject": "hello",
  "msgstring": "5",
  "unread": "1",
  "datetime": "Oct  1 2013  9:59PM",
  "orderid": "17",
  "recipient": [
      {
       "mbrname": "Jane Doe",
       "mbrhref": "/profile.aspx?mem=1227"
      },
      {
       "mbrname": "John Smith",
       "mbrhref": "/profile.aspx?mem=1337"
      }
],
  "message": [
      {
      "datetime":"2013-10-01T21:59:33.063",
      "sendname":"Jane Doe",
      "mbrhref":"/profile.aspx?mem=1227",
      "msgcontent": "<p>Hi. I would like to talk with you about Dwarf Beryl Beauty</p>"
      },
      {
      "datetime":"2013-11-26T16:29:17.037",
      "sendname":"John Smith",
      "mbrhref":"/profile.aspx?mem=1337",
      "msgcontent": "Tough luck."
       }
  ]
}
]
}
```

I don't necessarily need to use push to update the JSON file if there is a better way, I'm open to suggestions. I've verified my URL path is correct. Am I just missing something obvious? I'm new to JSON and only have passable jquery skills. Help!

Thanks in advance for any direction.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
data.message.push
```

instead of:

```
data.messageString.message.push
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I receive the same error with data.message.push

Answer (score 0):

Ah I see the issue, you have a local var and parameter of the same name `message`:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (messageString, message) { //here is param message
    var message = []; //here is a local var parameter

    message.push({ //this is probably referencing the parameter which is not an array or object that supports .push
```

Instead:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) { //I renamed the param to be more consistent with documentation, although it doesn't really matter, just will generate confusion

    data.messageString.push({ //modify the json we were passed in the data param
```

Comment: I don't want to overwrite, I want to add to the end. I've changed "var message = []" to "message = []" and am not getting an error, but it's still not updating the JSON file. :(

Comment: That's because you are creating a new empty array `= []` if you want to modify the json returned from getJSON then don't declare a variable and modify the parameter instead.  I'll update with example

Comment: @NicoleMcCoy If that doesn't work then you need to set a breakpoint and inspect the value of the data function to ensure getJSON is able to successfully parse what is being returned, and that the structure is an array as you expected.

Comment: Post the result of `console.log(data);` inside the function if that doesn't work

Comment: It does seem to parse what is being returned, but it is now throwing the error " data.push is not a function" Before when I set a break point and inspected push it showed as a function, now it says "undefined"

Comment: When I added "data=[]" to this, push once again showed as a function and the console.log logged my new data, but the JSON was not updated

Comment: When you do `data=[]` you are just replacing whatever object was passed in with an empty array, so you are not debugging the parameter in that case.  Take out the `data=[]` and the push(so it doesn't throw an error for now) and just do a `console.log(data)` because you need to figure out what the structure that is being passed in is.  I suspect it is not an array but instead some property inside it is an array

Comment: it looks like the exact structure of the JSON code I have above. I'm wanting to update the message array inside the messageString array.

Comment: Actually looks like you are trying to push to the nested message array, so it'd probably be something like `data.messageString[0].message.push(` but this will only work if you are assuming there is only one messageString in the array.  Hard to help beyond given the context

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your help. I think I can figure it out from here.